# Is the author of an open-source application obliged to make the "open-sourceness" visible?

Tags: open-source, licensing

What are the legal obligations to put into evidence that my application (I am the author) is open-source (especially when it is derivate), if I want to sell copies of it?

I mean, could my open-source application be sold, with all the licensing stuff and source code inside and not hidden, but without saying so in the advertising for the app in the app-store?

Comment: That would depend on the license used. Read it. Generally they want to be mentioned in "About" screens and such.

Comment: the license is GPL

Comment: What app store are you referring to?

Comment: I imagine the app store might have a reputation to maintain, and thus your user agreement with them might have a say in this.  The GPL doesn't require you to put anything in the advertising or the application itself, but as a customer, I would certainly be dismayed if I found out later that I bought from you something I could have obtained for free.  Don't you care about your own reputation at all?

Comment: selling copies of my open-source app is a right for others and not for me? @tripleee

Comment: I am not talking about your rights, I am talking about your customers' expectations. It would seem wiser to be up front about this; those who would rather compile the software themselves don't waste their money, and actually even those who do buy it from you might well feel good about being informed of their options.  This is certainly not legal advice.

Comment: You are right but my program is targeted at users that aren't able to compile.  The others can go to the "About" screen, I do not mind about their opinion for not being informed. GPL just wants to be mentioned in the "About" screen.

Comment: Of course the price would be low and support would be guaranteed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a requirement of the [open source definition](http://www.opensource.org/osd.html) that "The program must include source code, and must allow distribution in source code as well as compiled form." There is no requirement to prominently advertise the fact that your application is open source, but you must make the code available.

As an example, my TV runs Linux. If I go deep into the settings menu I can find an "licence" page that displays the licence and a URL to get the source. However, nowhere in the advertising or the handbook does it say anything about open source.

NOTE: Many app-store terms and conditions prevent some types of open source license being deployed on their service. See [App Stores and Openess](http://www.oss-watch.ac.uk/resources/appstores.xml) for more information.